# Large 1/4 inch 45 degree chamfer router bit for cutting mitres

Tags: router, router-bit, router-table, mitre

I am wanting to perform some mitre 45 degree cuts with my router table as my cheapo mitre saw doesn't have a straight fence (*sad noises*); so I've been looking for a chamfer bit that is large enough to perform mitre cuts on my thicker than normal pine stock - I believe it is 22mm thick.

From the youtube videos I've watched it seems that the **45 degree heavy duty chamfer bit 36-950** from [Infinity Tools](https://www.infinitytools.co.uk/router-bits/chamfer-bit/) is the go to bit for this sort of job, however it also appears that this only comes in 1/2 inch shank :-(

I'm just wondering if there is a bit out there that I have not seen that can do something similar, or can I accomplish the mitre cut with a smaller, standard sized chamfer bit that I already own (with bearing)?

Comment: A bit (no pun intended) late to the party , but have you considered making a straight fence for your mitre saw? That would eliminate having to make jigs and/or purchasing a wide variety of router bits to do things that your miter saw is perfectly capable of doing with some minor tweaks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> From the youtube videos I've watched it seems that the 45 degree heavy duty chamfer bit 36-950 from Infinity Tools is the go to bit for this sort of job, however it also appears that this only comes in 1/2 inch shank :-(

When the cutter approaches or exceeds the cost of a new router (and perhaps it's worth mentioning that routers litter the secondhand-tool market) some would argue that the maths becomes very simple.... assuming space isn't so tight that you couldn't squeeze another router into the workshop.

However....

**Approach the problem from a different direction**
Straight bit, angled workpiece. Standard way in some workshops to machine mitres, and not just with a router.

Making a jig for any given mitre is straightforward (or take a bit more time and make a fancy one, adjustable for all conceivable angles) and then you only have to buy straight bits to cover almost all the work you'd do on board ends, from basic shooting to tenon forming and mitre cutting.

Comment: I've literally just bought a new 1/4 inch router to replace the one I broke last week XD If I'd have known about the limited size of the router bit, I might have spen a little more on a 1/2 inch one. Your advice in change of approach is very interesting though! I will have a go at making some sort of jig. I do actually have some 45 degree offcut triangles laying around the shed!

Answer (score 6):

> it also appears that this only comes in 1/2 inch shank

A 45° cutter that's large enough to cut the full 22mm thickness of your work will have to be *at least* 44mm in diameter, plus the diameter of the shaft, for a total of 51mm or more. You wouldn't want a sharpened chunk of metal that large spinning at 10,000rpm or more on a 1/4" shank.

> I'm just wondering if there is a bit out there that I have not seen that can do something similar

Most router bits meant for making miter joints are actually lock miter bits, which doesn't sound like what you want. And I've never seen one with a shank smaller than 1/2".

> can I accomplish the mitre cut with a smaller, standard sized chamfer bit that I already own (with bearing)?

No. It'd be very difficult to cut an accurate miter joint in multiple passes with a small 45° bit.

> I am wanting to perform some mitre 45 degree cuts with my router table as my cheapo mitre saw doesn't have a straight fence

Can you do anything to fix that? Maybe make replacement fences from plywood? That'd be far preferable to trying to use a router that's not up to the task.

Comment: Lock-mitre bits are available with 1/4" and 8mm shanks. [Here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1000004518429.html)'s one on AliExpress.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Caleb - I thought it might be the case of one not being available. oh well.. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Seems that fixing the fence on the miter saw should be a priority for a vast number of reasons. Or, instead of spending on a huge bit, put that toward a replacement saw if yours is that cheap...

Comment: @Graphus To clarify, I've never seen a lock miter bit in the size the OP needs with a 1/4" shank; the one you linked to is about half the size needed.

Answer (score 0):

Physicisboy. There is a bit from Yonico that can cut a height of 11/16”. You maybe able to cut your 3/4” piece and then raise up or down bit another 1/16+ to finish the cut. I’m not sure it will work. I haven’t tried it.

If you move it down you have a bump on the bottom you can hand plane off.

Tools today has one that can remove up to 23/32”. That one will get you closer.

You’ll need a router table.
I know I’m late to this forum but I’m having the same problem.

I hope this helps.